# Problems running a C# C++/CLI wrapper solution on x64

Tags: c#, c++, .net, visual-studio, wrapper

I am using Visual Studio 2019 version 16.11.10. I am trying to do a small C# project that can communicate with an C++ object with functions. What i understand was that i have to use something called C++/CLI wrapper.

I tried to follow this tutorial: [redgate - Creating a C++/CLI Wrapper](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/development/dotnet-development/creating-ccli-wrapper/)

The project consists of one solution with 3 projects. The three projects are Sandbox (C# project), Wrapper (C++/CLI wrapper project) and Core (C++ project).

A detail about the Core-project is that you have to configure it as Static library (.lib). To do it you will Right-click on the Core-project and select Properties. Under General we select Static library (.lib).

A detail about the Wrapper-project is that you have select “Not Using Precompiled Headers” at Properties->C/C++->Precompiled Headers

I have done some kind of x86/x64 “alignment” for the projects in the Configuration Manager. If i select x86 as solution platform i will set Sandbox to x86, Core to Win32 and Wrapper to Win32. If i select x64 as solution platform i will set Sandbox, Core and Wrapper to x64

I had problems to run the solution on x86. The problem was that Wrapper and Sandbox used different .NET-versions. So now, if both use the same .NET-version (for example .NET 3.1 or .NET 5) for Wrapper and Sandbox, then i can run the solution on x86.

I have problems running the solution on x64. When i run it i get this error:

> Microsoft Visual Studio
>
> The debug executable
> 'C:\Users\Philip\kodning2\vsworkdir\egnaTestProjekt\Solution_CLIExample3\Core\Sandbox\bin\x64\Debug\net5.0\Sandbox.exe'
> specified in the 'Sandbox' debug profile does not exist.
>
> OK

I also get these Errors:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol main referenced in function "int __cdecl invoke_main(void)" (?invoke_main@@YAHXZ)    Core    C:\Users\Philip\kodning2\vsworkdir\egnaTestProjekt\Solution_CLIExample3\Core\Core\MSVCRTD.lib(exe_main.obj) 1   
Error   C1010   unexpected end of file while looking for precompiled header. Did you forget to add '#include "pch.h"' to your source?   Wrapper C:\Users\Philip\kodning2\vsworkdir\egnaTestProjekt\Solution_CLIExample3\Core\Wrapper\Entity.cpp 16  
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'Entity' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)    Sandbox C:\Users\Philip\kodning2\vsworkdir\egnaTestProjekt\Solution_CLIExample3\Core\Sandbox\Program.cs 9   Active
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'Entity' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)    Sandbox C:\Users\Philip\kodning2\vsworkdir\egnaTestProjekt\Solution_CLIExample3\Core\Sandbox\Program.cs 9   Active
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'CLI' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   Sandbox C:\Users\Philip\kodning2\vsworkdir\egnaTestProjekt\Solution_CLIExample3\Core\Sandbox\Program.cs 2   Active
Error   CS0006  Metadata file 'C:\Users\Philip\kodning2\vsworkdir\egnaTestProjekt\Solution_CLIExample3\Core\x64\Debug\Wrapper.dll' could not be found   Sandbox C:\Users\Philip\kodning2\vsworkdir\egnaTestProjekt\Solution_CLIExample3\Core\Sandbox\CSC    1   Active
Error   LNK1120 1 unresolved externals  Core    C:\Users\Philip\kodning2\vsworkdir\egnaTestProjekt\Solution_CLIExample3\Core\x64\Debug\Core.exe 1
```

How to be able to run this solution as x64? What i am doing wrong?

EDIT1:

As Alan Birtles suggested, i post the text from the Output-window:

```
Build started...
1>------ Build started: Project: Core, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
Restored C:\Users\Philip\kodning2\vsworkdir\egnaTestProjekt\Solution_CLIExample3\Core\Sandbox\Sandbox.csproj (in 3 ms).
1>Entity.cpp
1>MSVCRTD.lib(exe_main.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol main referenced in function "int __cdecl invoke_main(void)" (?invoke_main@@YAHXZ)
1>C:\Users\Philip\kodning2\vsworkdir\egnaTestProjekt\Solution_CLIExample3\Core\x64\Debug\Core.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
1>Done building project "Core.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
2>------ Build started: Project: Wrapper, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
2>pch.cpp
2>AssemblyInfo.cpp
2>Entity.cpp
2>C:\Users\Philip\kodning2\vsworkdir\egnaTestProjekt\Solution_CLIExample3\Core\Wrapper\Entity.cpp(16,1): fatal error C1010: unexpected end of file while looking for precompiled header. Did you forget to add '#include "pch.h"' to your source?
2>Wrapper.cpp
2>Generating Code...
2>Done building project "Wrapper.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
3>------ Build started: Project: Sandbox, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
3>CSC : error CS0006: Metadata file 'C:\Users\Philip\kodning2\vsworkdir\egnaTestProjekt\Solution_CLIExample3\Core\x64\Debug\Wrapper.dll' could not be found
3>Done building project "Sandbox.csproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 3 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: Can you delete the contents of the folder, rebuild and post the file listing here as well?

Comment: Please post the errors as shown in the compiler window rather than from the error window which is just a summary of the compiler output

Comment: Alan Birtles, i guess you mean the Output-window. I am new to Visual Studio and C# CLI CLR etc. by the way. I updated my post accordingly. 
Stefan, thank you but what folder do you mean? I guessed you mean C:\Users\Philip\kodning2\vsworkdir\egnaTestProjekt\Solution_CLIExample3\Core\Sandbox\bin\x64\Debug . I Deleted it and run the solution again, but the same errors occurs. What do you mean with file listing?

Comment: It might be that your .lib file is compiled for x86. I would suggest reviewing the project properties, specifically linker\advanced->targetMachine and any library and dependency directories. The Visual studio platforms and configuration manager can be a bit difficult to use, so problems might not be completely unexpected..

Comment: Thank you JonasH. But I can't find any targetMachine or similar for the Core (C++-project). But on the of the Properties page i see "Platform: Active(x64)" of course.
For the Wrapper-project: Configuration Properties->Linker->Advanced->Target Machine someone had choosen MachineX64 for me already.
For the Sandbox-project: Build->Platform target someone have choosen x64 for me.

Comment: Is core supposed to be a dll? It looks like it's configured to be an executable and is therefore failing to build as you haven't provided a `main` function. Wrapper is failing due to precompiled headers, either turn them off or make sure the pch is included in every cpp file. Sandbox is failing because wrapper is failing. This is why it's important to look in the output window it's clearer there that some errors are simply a side effect of earlier errors

Comment: The problem should come from the compatibility of the dynamic library, you should choose x86 at the beginning, so you can't run the program in a 64-bit environment. If you only want to run in a 64-bit environment, you should consider rebuilding the program.